# how to authenticate REST in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, rest, playframework-1.x

i have an application of play that need to be secure. i have try to import module secure, it working the application need login now, and now i have another problem. I want to authenticate from REST. I mean how client request to my application for authenticate?, i have try like this

```
public static Response logIn(){
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(request.body);
    String request;
    response.status = 400;
    try {
        while(null != ((request = dis.readLine()))){
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
            String username = jsonObject.getString("username");
            String password = jsonObject.getString("password");
            boolean authenticated = Security.authenticate(username, password);
            if(authenticated){
                response.status = 200;
                return response;
            }else{
                response.status = 400;
                return response;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

but when i test it with rest client, it error, it say that server redirected too many. Sorry for my bad English, i want an example if that posible

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of ready decisions, for example [play authenticate plugin](http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/#sample_application) or use [this article](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide4)